Why is ClerkProvider not working in Next.js 14 and showing "cannot be used as a JSX component"?
I am trying to integrate Clerk into my Next.js 14 app by wrapping the RootLayout in the ClerkProvider. However, I keep encountering this error:

'ClerkProvider' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its type '(props:
Without<NextClerkProviderProps,
"__unstable_invokeMiddlewareOnAuthStateChange">) => Promise'
is not a valid JSX element type. Type '(props:
Without<NextClerkProviderProps,
"__unstable_invokeMiddlewareOnAuthStateChange">) => Promise'
is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any)
=> ReactNode'. Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <body
          className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable} antialiased`}
        >
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}

I have already:

Followed official documentation
Installed the latest version of @clerk/nextjs using npm install @clerk/nextjs@latest.
Verified that my Next.js version is 14 and the app directory is being used.
Configured middleware.ts for Clerk.

Thanks in advance

I found an answer from Clerk Discord that is working for me:

Hey folks, we've have quite a few reports of users running into this type of error when spinning up new NextJs apps or upgrading older apps. Here's how to resolve the error:
This error is caused by @types/react version 18.3.14. If you run into this issue we recommend the following versions.
If using Next 15, you'll have to have the following versions to >resolve the error:
"next": "15.0.4",
"react": "^19.0.0",
"react-dom": "^19.0.0",
"@types/react": "^19.0.1",


If using Next 14, you can utilize the following versions:
"next": "14.2.20",
"react": "^18.3.1",
"react-dom": "^18.3.1",
"@types/react": "^18.3.12",
You'll have to stay on this version until this [PR][1] is merged.
PR: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/71388


I am having the same error. It seems like NextJS v14.2 have changed the types definitions and @clerk/nextjs is not able to catch up.
I would say, give it a few days until clerk team release a minor update to fix this linting error.

i was also facing the same issue i guess there is some error in the latest version so just downgrade your clerk version and everything will work good !!

This basically sums up https://stackoverflow.com/a/79270044/20731770. Instead of creating a new answer you can upvote or thank @antonioc_cl answer.

Update to react 19 and latest version of clerk
npm install --save-exact react@^19.0.0 react-dom@^19.0.0 --legacy-peer-deps

